# Passing Value from asp.net page to another page using textbox and able to edit also

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm actually newbie in ASP.NET..

I've created 2 pages named Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx

so, I tried this method to Display the value that was entered on Textbox to another Page on the textbox

Here's the Code using vb.net

Page1

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="proceed" runat="server" Text="Proceed" />
        Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?Value=" + Textbox1.Text)
        End Sub
```

Page2

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Request.QueryString("Value")) Then
          Textbox1.Text = Request.QueryString("Value")
    End If
End Sub
```

that is working on my webpage but the problem is:

on the Page2.aspx. I have a button that will Edit the value on the textbox that was received from the Page1.aspx.. but it doesn't... what should i do in order to edit the value on the textbox in Page2.aspx...

Thank you in advanced...

I hope this is a clear question for you guys

Comment: do you want it to be changed int he Page1 ?

Comment: no.. i want to change the value of a textbox in page2.aspx so that i've created a button named edit.. in order to change the value...

Comment: but where is it stored ? i mean the value isit in a database or a file or something ?

Comment: the value was stored on the textbox of page1.aspx.. so that if i click the Button named Button1 and it will proceed on the next page which is Page2.aspx and it will get the value from the textbox of Page1.aspx

Comment: so you want to see what you typed in Page1 in Page2 right ?

Comment: yeah but that is working also on my web page.. but as I said i've create Button also on the Page2.aspx Named Edit.. but I don't know the Command on how I will change its Value... and that is the Problem...

Comment: I'm sorry If you are having Difficult time to understand my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each postback to server the Page_Load method will call again,so when you click the button before  your  Button_Click method, the Page_Load method will execute and it will modify the textbox value. try this:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 if (Page.IsPostBack) Then return;
        If (Request.QueryString("Value")) Then
              Textbox1.Text = Request.QueryString("Value")
        End If
    End Sub
```

running website with breakpoins could help you to figure out the problem.